# How Does Composite Column PartitionKey Work in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to figure out what advantages that a compound partition key can provide. Look at the famous weather station example below.

CREATE TABLE temperature (
state text,
city text,
event_time timestamp,
temperature text,
PRIMARY KEY (**(state, city)**,event_time)
);

Now, I most of time query into one single state on a set of cities and a range of dates. So the query is like

`SELECT * FROM temperature WHERE state = 'NY' AND city IN ('mahattan', 'brooklyn','queens') AND event_time > '2016-01-01'`.

Assuming I have a large data set, in sense that I have a few states (# < 1000) but for each state I have many many cities ( # > 100M). I replicate the data and distribute them into different nodes.

Question: can you compare the differences using

```
PRIMARY KEY (**(state, city)**,event_time)

PRIMARY KEY (**(city, state)**,event_time)

PRIMARY KEY (state, city,event_time)

PRIMARY KEY (zipcode, event_time)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Composite Key

```
PRIMARY KEY (**(state, city)**,event_time)
PRIMARY KEY (**(city, state)**,event_time)
```

Are functionally equivalent. The composite partition key will be the combined values of city and state. You will be unable to fully specify a partition without both portions. Within the partition cells will be ordered by `event_time`. You will have `#State * #City` Partitions

```
[city, state] -> [event_time_0, event_time_1, event_time_2, event_time_3, ...]
```

You will be able to write queries like

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CITY = X AND STATE = Y AND event_time (><=) SomeValue
```

## Compound Keys

```
PRIMARY KEY (state, city,event_time)
```

One partition is made for every state. This is probably bad since there are on the order of 100x state/provinces which means you will only have a very small number of partitions. Data will be laid out within the partition by city and event_time.

```
[Illinois] --> [Chicago, 0], [Chicago, 1], [Peoria, 0], [Peoria, 1]
```

Queries will have to restrict city if they are also restricting event time.

```
PRIMARY KEY (zipcode, event_time)
```

You will have up to 10k Partitions, each will have a single cell for each event time.

Comment: PRIMARY KEY ((state, city),event_time) vs PRIMARY KEY (zipcode, event_time)  which one is better? Lets assume zipcode is unique for each city - state. Say if I have 2 states and each has 3 cities, then I have 6 zipcodes in total. So should I prefer higher # of partitions?

Comment: You almost always want more partitions and I imagine zipcodes is more likely to have an equivalent amount of events than cities (since zipcodes are supposed to be normalized based on pop I think)